# Duplicating blog feed without upsetting SEO

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, rss, feeds

My client owns two websites and on one of them he wishes to copy the blog feed from the other site and insert it. The problem with this is that Google is generally unhappy with duplicated content - Otherwise I was looking to develop an RSS feed version of the blog in site 1 and parse it / generate it with site 2.

How can i perform this ethically without 'duplicate content' issues for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This is textbook duplicate content. Either use canonical URLs, don't let the duplicate site be crawled and indexed, or don't duplicate the site. But definitely don't expect there to be anyway to have the same content twice without being penalized for duplicate content.